# Multiplying two arrays

Tags: c++, matrix

I would like to ask how I can make my code more simple and effective. I know that this code can be 100% better. I am supposed to load number for each array and then take the 2 arrays (4*3 and 3*4) and multiply them into 3*3 array.

The main point is making the`scanf_`s for both `int a` and `int b` in one "piece of code."

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[3][4];
    int b[4][3];
    int c[3][3] = { {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} };

    for (int j = 0; j != 4; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l != 4; l++)
        {
            cout << "Zadej a[" << j << "," << l << "]: ";
            scanf_s("%d", &a[j][l]);
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j != 4; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l != 4; l++)
        {
            cout << "Zadej b[" << j << "," << l << "]: ";
            scanf_s("%d", &b[j][l]);
        }
    }


    for (int j = 0; j != 3; j++)
    {
        for (int l = 0; l != 3; l++)
        {
            ;
            printf(" |%d| ", c[j][l] += a[j][l] * b[j][l]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Is the code working the right way ?"_ It's you who's in charge to ensure that, before asking for a review here.

Comment: Don't take me the wrong way, _it is working_ but I have never done anything with matrixes yet so I am not sure if I'm counting it the right way.

Comment: Write appropriate test cases first to the best of your knowledge.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I am absolutely certain that it works the right way so if you could kindly help me with the other two points I would be glad.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Your new code was barely an improvement compared to the old code. Please wait a while longer, more answers might be incoming. Feel free to take another good look at it yourself as well. Should you write a piece that's definitely improved, write a follow-up question linking back to this one for bonus context.

Comment: @PatrikŠoukal in [that revision](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/211634/4) you added a question... you could put that question in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/341145) on Toby's answer (though won't be able to put the updated code block in, since it would be too long)

Comment: That is not matrix multiplication. One good hint that you’re not doing it right is that you don’t use all of the elements of `a` and `b`. Look for “matrix multiplication” on Wikipedia, I’m sure you can find an algorithm there for how you should compute this.

Comment: ...Sorry, Wikipedia was bad advice, that is terribly obtusely written. [Here is a better explanation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for pointing that out, honestly I didn't notice that I need to use one more for loop. The code should look like this: ‘for (j = 0, i < 3, i++)
      for (l = 0, j < 3, j++)
         C[i][j] = 0
           for (k = 0, k < 4, k++)
              C[j][l] += A[j][k] * B[k][l]‘

Answer (score 3):

## Don't put everything into one big `main()`

If you can separate out the reading of inputs and writing of results from the actual multiplications, then it will be easier to test the multiplication code separately.

## Avoid non-standard libraries

Here we have `"stdafx.h"` and `scanf_s` that aren't part of standard C++.  Ditch those and use the standard facilities (e.g. `std::cin >> a[j][l]`).

## Include what you use

We don't seem to use `<cmath>` anywhere, so let's drop that.  We'll need `<cstdio>` for `std::printf()` - or switch to C++ style output using `<iostream>`.

## Avoid using the whole `std` namespace

The `std` namespace isn't one of the few that's designed to be imported wholesale like that, and there's potential for name conflicts when moving to a new standards version.  Specify just the names you need, or just get used to writing `std::` - it's intentionally very short.

## Use C++ collections

It's easier to work with the C++ collection types such as `std::array` or `std::vector` than with raw (C-style) arrays (which decay to pointers when passed as function arguments).

Comment: So I edited the code a bit but now it posts an error: "no operator "<<" matches these operands". Also now that I removed the [] brackets how am I supposed to change the x/y the same way I did before?

`std::array<int, 3> a;
    std::array<int, 4> b;
    std::array<int, 3> c;`